# different behavior of ipad app in debug mode with ipad and release mode (adhoc) for exact same conditions.

Tags: ios

I'm stuck with this weird problem.I have a method that clears the related `UIObjects` values which works fine in simulator and **debug mode using ipad** but after archiving and downloading same app (adhoc release) the method shows different behavior.As it work fine in debug mode I'v traced using alert in every conditions of method and it shows different behavior.

//Method

```
-(void)NAclicked:(UIViewController *)controller ofId:(id)sender
{
  UIView *newCheck = (UIView * )sender;
  int i=newCheck.tag;

  NSLog(@"id %d",i);
  bool fromGroup4 = [controller isKindOfClass:[G4S16_FunctionalStatusEvaluation class]];
  if([newCheck isKindOfClass:[CheckBoxNE class]] || ([controller isKindOfClass:[G4S16_FunctionalStatusEvaluation class]] && [sender isKindOfClass:[CheckBoxNASN     class]]))
  {
    bool condition = false;
    if(fromGroup4)
    {
       CheckBoxNASN* cb = (CheckBoxNASN*)sender;
       condition = ([cb.Value isEqualToString:@"NA"]);  
    }
    else
    {
        CheckBoxNE* cb = (CheckBoxNE*)sender;
        if([[cb Value] intValue]==1)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d",([[cb Value] intValue]==1));
            condition = true;
        }
    }
    if(condition)
    {
        NSManagedObject *question =[self getQuestionObjectFromQuestionElementId:((UIButton *)sender).tag];
        int questionId = [[question valueForKey:@"id"]intValue];
        NSArray *arrQuestionElements= [self getQuestionElementsFromQuestion:questionId];
        for(int j=0;j<[arrQuestionElements count];j++)
        {

            QuestionElements *questionElements = [arrQuestionElements objectAtIndex:j];
            NSLog(@"Question Element %@",questionElements.id);
            if([questionElements.id intValue]==i)
                continue;
            UIView *new = (UIView * )[controller.view viewWithTag:[questionElements.id intValue]];

            if([new isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton* btnDD = (UIButton*)new;
                [btnDD setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                btnDD.titleLabel.text=@"";
                [self saveAnswer:btnDD.tag AnswerText:@""];
            }
            else if([new isKindOfClass:[DWOptionGroup class]])
            {
                DWOptionGroup* btnCB = (DWOptionGroup*)new;
                [btnCB setValue:@""];
                [self saveAnswer:btnCB.tag AnswerText:@""];

            }
            else if([new isKindOfClass : [CheckBox class]])
            {
                CheckBox* btnCB = (CheckBox*)new;
                [btnCB setValue:0];
                [self saveAnswer:btnCB.tag AnswerText:@""];

            }
            else if([new isKindOfClass : [UITextField class]])
            {   
                UITextField * txtCB = (UITextField *)new;
                txtCB.text=@"";
                [self saveAnswer:txtCB.tag AnswerText:@""];   

            }
            else 
            {
                    //testing
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Testing" 
                                                                    message:@"nothing to clear."
                                                                   delegate:nil 
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];

                    [alert show];
                    //  
            }

        }


    }
}
else
{
    [self removeNA:controller ofId:sender];            
}
}
```

Conditions and results

**In debug mode**

if there are four question elements (i.e arrQuestionElements.count=4).

1)UIButton

2)DWOptionGroup

3)CheckBox

4)UITextField

in each loop it enter respective if conditions.
1st loop=if([new isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])

2nd loop=else if([new isKindOfClass:[DWOptionGroup class]])

and so on.

**But in adhoc release for same condition traced using alert.**

1st loop=else part

2nd loop=else part

3rd loop=else part

and 
4th loop=else if([new isKindOfClass : [UITextField class]])    (works fine for last of the loop)

similarly,if the last object is UIButton

1st loop=else part

2nd loop=else part

3rd loop=else part

and 
4th loop=if([new isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])    (works fine for last of the loop)

Any suggestion regarding this issue would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.